# How should I provide a hosted service on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, saas, hosted

If i want to rent space on my service which I in turn host on Google App Service, is there some Terms of Service i need to know about?

Also, if I want to provide a service that should be customized for a company, say a Wiki that the company can tailor like their own with skins and even domains. Can that be done? Will I have to provide the binaries to be installed at my customer's Google App accounts? E.g. my wiki application would run at wiki.company.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything in the TOS that prevents you from selling your software as a service on GAE.

The domain issue is a bit trickier at the moment, however, as there are relatively limited tools for attaching large numbers of domain names to a single app instance.  Your best bet at the moment would likely be to purchase Google for domains accounts for each customer and host them on these separate accounts.

(cf [Issue 113](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=113))

Comment: Also, this document may be helpful: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html